# Why does Java require EnumClass.VALUE instead of just VALUE?

Tags: java, enums

If you have a Java `enum` and a variable of the enum's type, as so:

```
public enum Something
{
   VAL1,
   VAL2,
   VAL3
}

public Something varName;
```

why is it necessary to write `varName = Something.VAL1;` instead of simply `varName = VAL1;`? Shouldn't the compiler know from the type of `varName` that it can only take `null`, `VAL1`, `VAL2`, and `VAL3` as values?

Comment: No. Enum values aren't global (except in switches, it seems).

Comment: What if `Something` implements an interface (`Serializable`, for example), and you want to declare `varName` as a `Serializable`.  How would the compiler know that you are trying to declare from that particular enum, versus any other serializable type?  The language is designed to allow a variable to be typed as any of its supertypes, and this wouldn't be possible with your suggested enum declaration style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The righthand side of the `=` statement is an expression, which is parsed generically. Anyway, to show how it could be complicated for the compiler, consider this:

```
public enum Something { VAL1, VAL2, VAL3 }

Something VAL3 = Something.VAL1;

Something a = VAL3;
```

Should `a` be assigned `VAL1` or `VAL3`?

The only time you don't need the enum name is in a `switch` statement, because the `case` statements **must** use a valid enum value, so the enum name is unnecessary.

```
switch (a) {
    case VAL1:
        // do something
        break;
    case VAL2:
        // do something
        break;
    case VAL3:
        // do something
        break;
}
```

Comment: This is a good point, and well stated. I guess, as ruahk suggests in his answer, I don't' hate the readers of my code enough for such a construct to even cross my mind.

Answer (score 4):

This is a good question. Offhand, the only reason I can think of is that something like this is perfectly valid (provided you hate the people reading your code):

```
public class Evil {
     public enum FooBar { FOO, BAR }
     public static FooBar FOO = FooBar.BAR;

     private FooBar baz = FOO;    // means Evil.FOO, i.e. FooBar.BAR
}
```

Java does have some type inference (for example, `final List<String> emptyStringList = java.util.Collections.emptyList()` is equivalent to `final List<String> emptyStringList = java.util.Collections.<String>emptyList()`, and has been since Java 5), but this type inference never alters the meaning of an expression, it only ever selects a single meaning for an otherwise-ambiguous expression.

Comment: LOL Like the comment about hating the people that read your code. BTW: It's a coding pattern called "Obfuscation": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29

Comment: A good point, especially about hating the readers of your code. I've never hated them enough for such a construct to even cross my mind. Of course, I happen to be the main reader of my code...

Answer (score 1):

If you have two enums defining `VAL1`, how can the compiler know which one are you referring to?

Nevertheless, static imports may make things a bit more readable:

```
import static Something.VAL1;
```

Comment: By the type, I would assume. It is ever valid to set a variable of type `Something` to a value of type `SomethingElse`, when `SomethingElse` does not inherit from `Something`?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't, always. It does most of the time to resolve the ambiguity that would arise if all the scopes of all the in-scope enums were automatically opened, but there is one case where it does open the scope of one enum: the `switch` statement:

```
Enum MyEnum
{
    Value1;
}
MyEnum value = ...;
switch (myEnumValue)
{
case Value1:
    //
    break;
}
```